# Does Azure support client operating systems (ie Windows 7)?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I am trying to setup a Windows 7 Virtual Machine in Azure and I see a list of Windows Server options, but not a plain Windows 7 Professional.

I need Windows 7 for testing purposes.

**Do they only support server VMs?**

**Edit:** After Searching I found that *Windows 7 Enterprise N* is supported.  I guess I could use that.  But it seems lame that they would not support something so common as Windows 7 Professional...

Comment: This should be posted to ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 (and all Windows client OSs) are not supported, or more importantly, licensed for use on ANY cloud service.

Azure gets around this limitation by only allowing Windows Client machines to be run as MSDN development machines. (I imagine being Microsoft helps too)

If you have an MSDN subscription, you will have access to Win7, Win8, and Win10 machines.

So if you wanted to build a business running Windows client machines, licensing would restrict that, but if you're using it as a development machine, that is ok.

So you couldn't, for instance, give everyone in an office access to a Win 10 Machine on Azure.

Comment: I noticed you've been answering a bunch of questions lately. For ones like these, you should encourage the OP to post on ServerFault instead of StackOverflow when they're infrastructure-related and not programming-related (since they're off-topic here).

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  However, I do have a MSDN Subscription.  But the only Windows 7 option I could find after searching (with MSDN enabled) was "Windows 7 Enterprise N".